# How to save an image file?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this segment of code:

```
    Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Desktop\Sample Pictures"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Pictures|*.jpg|Text|*.txt"

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then

              ' Insert code to read the stream here.

            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I need to copy the file in **myStream** to some destination Folder.
Any idea how I can implement it?

Comment: why reading the file and than recreate it? if all you want to do is copy to another directoyion you can use System.IO.File.Copy() method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx

Comment: Or use My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile().  Buys you a nice animation with the flying file folder, useful if copying the file takes a while.  And can be cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the `myDestinationDir` is the path where you want to copy your file then

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 
    ' Extract the filename part from the full filename returned by openDialog.'
    Dim selectedFile As String = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    ' Append to the destinationDir the filename extracted'
    Dim destFile As String = Path.Combine(myDestinationDir, selectedFile)
    ' Copy with overwrite (if overwrite is not desidered, use the overload with False as 3 arg'
    System.IO.File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, destFile)
End Sub
```

This will copy the selected file to the destination folder overwriting an existing file with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(myStream);
```

or

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
```

and than, save by:

```
img.Save("new location");
```

[samples are in C#]

Answer (score 0):

This is snippet from real code I wrote for some experimenting software.

```
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim fStream As FileStream
    Dim fileName As String

    Try
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Get path from textbox
    strPath = txtSavePath.Text.ToLower

    'Check directory existence, if not, create it
    If Directory.Exists(strPath) Then

    Else
        Try
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath)
        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Error in Creating Directory, Code : " & ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End If

    'Set current active directory
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(strPath)

    'Create Filename
    fileName = txtFileName.Text.ToUpper & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss")


    'Write/Create file
    fStream = File.Open(fileName & ".png", FileMode.Create)
    fStream.Write(byteData, 0, nLength)
    fStream.Close()
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Display On Window
        picGraphDisplay.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(fileName & ".png")
        txtSavedFileName.Text = fileName & ".png"
    Catch ex As Exception
        CheckVisaStatus(errorStatus)
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

    End Try
```

In this case, the filestream is writing byte data of an image into a file. Where you take the byte image from is up to you. In this case, also a good idea is to employ a specific name for your files, done here by using the system's `DateTime.Now`.

Hope it gave you some ideas. Cheers

Comment: You don't seem to address the situation the OP has here.